# Pass parameter skip=1 in readxl::read_excel() leads to last empty column missing

Tags: r, readxl

Given a sample excel file from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/h156apr4hhf7x5wuv8y11/reprex.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=huw857f8x3yeg5qsr192zuxlq), I attempted to use `readxl::read_excel` to read files while skipping headers and renaming with new names.

The code below works just fine for `Sheet2` with no empty columns inside.

```
xlsx_file <- '~/reprex.xlsx'
sheets_to_read <- readxl::excel_sheets(xlsx_file)

col_names <- c("names", 'error', 'log_error', 'value1', 'value2', 'acc_score')

readxl::read_excel(xlsx_file,
           sheet = 'Sheet2',
           skip = 1,
           col_names=col_names)
```

Out:

```
  names error log_error value1 value2           acc_score
  <chr> <lgl> <lgl>     <lgl>  <chr>            <chr>    
1 agri  NA    NA        NA     6.32929944992065 right    
2 indus NA    NA        NA     11.21162109375   right    
3 oil   NA    NA        NA     1.45932525119925 right    
4 metal NA    NA        NA     2.10280250811577 right
```

But for `Sheet1`, since there are empty columns inside (columns such as: error, LogError, score, etc.), it raises an `Error: Sheet 1 has 7 columns (7 unskipped), but col_names has length 6.`

After I searched, this issue may be related to the question [from here](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/577).

So I wonder how could we modify my code `readxl::read_excel(...)` to coordinate with the case as in `Sheet1`, which means include all empty columns inside excel file?

**EDIT:** if we don't add parameter: `skip = 1`, it could read all columns read excel file:

```
> readxl::read_excel(xlsx_file,
+            sheet = 'Sheet2',
+            # skip = 1,
+            # col_names=col_names
+            )
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  name  error LogError `2022-01-31` `2022-01-31 pred` direction score
  <chr> <lgl> <lgl>    <lgl>        <chr>             <chr>     <lgl>
1 agri  NA    NA       NA           6.32929944992065  right     NA   
2 indus NA    NA       NA           11.21162109375    right     NA   
3 oil   NA    NA       NA           1.45932525119925  right     NA   
4 metal NA    NA       NA           2.10280250811577  right     NA
```

After skipping the first row, we can see the last empty column missing, so the question is how to prevent this? Any helps or comments will be appreciated.

```
> readxl::read_excel(xlsx_file,
+            sheet = 'Sheet2',
+            skip = 1,
+            # col_names=col_names
+            )
New names:
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
* `` -> ...4
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  agri  ...2  ...3  ...4  `6.32929944992065` right
  <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>              <chr>
1 indus NA    NA    NA    11.21162109375     right
2 oil   NA    NA    NA    1.45932525119925   right
3 metal NA    NA    NA    2.10280250811577   right
```

Pass `col_type='text'`:

```
> readxl::read_excel('reprex.xlsx',
+                    sheet = 'Sheet2',
+                    # skip = 1,
+                    # col_names=col_names,
+                    col_types = 'text'
+                    )
# A tibble: 4 × 7                                                                                                               
  name  error LogError `2022-01-31` `2022-01-31 pred` direction score
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>        <chr>             <chr>     <chr>
1 agri  NA    NA       NA           6.32929944992065  right     NA   
2 indus NA    NA       NA           11.21162109375    right     NA   
3 oil   NA    NA       NA           1.45932525119925  right     NA   
4 metal NA    NA       NA           2.10280250811577  right     NA
```

**Reference:**

https://readxl.tidyverse.org/reference/read_excel.html

Comment: I'm surprised there are so many NA columns.  If you pass `col_types = "text"`, are they still NA?

Comment: The problems seems raised by last NA column, I've added new result after passing `col_types = "text"`.

Comment: Why do you want to skip the header?  In other words, why are you not satisfied with your 2nd & 4th call (*e.g.*, `readxl::read_excel(xlsx_file, sheet = 'Sheet2')`)?

Comment: Because I wanna to rename each sheet with `col_names <- c("names", 'error', 'log_error', 'value1', 'value2', 'acc_score')`, so I skip the original headers by setting `skip=1`